# Get the last hash after the hash has changed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browser-history

I've a backbone app where I wanna open an overlay wich is just a page with its on url. You can also navigate in this overlay with different pages/urls. So when the overlay is closed I wanna set back the hash to the state before the overlay was opened. As the overlay is opened by a link I can't get the hash from the state before.

So is there a way to get the previous hash when a hash changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hashchange event has a "oldURL" field.... store all the "oldURL" (or only the last one) and, when you need it, change the actual url with the last url.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange

Comment: Saving `oldUrl` and get back to old position by `window.location.replace(oldUrl)` is the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this little hack. When the the overlay is opened I store the `window.history.length`. When the overlay is closed I call `window.history.go` with the difference between the stored length and the actual and subtract 1.

```
var appStateActions = {
  overlayPre: function(){
    this.historyPosition = window.history.length;
  },
  overlayExit: function(){
    window.history.go(this.historyPosition - window.history.length -1);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work cause of the limit of the history. So you get a wrong result after you reach the the limit of history length.

Answer (score 0):

```
var historyurl =[];

$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    historyurl.push(location.hash); 
   if(historyurl.length > 2){ 
       historyurl.splice(0,historyurl.length-2)
     }; 
});

console.log("Last Hah Url ="+historyurl[0])
```